# Why did flux failed decoding Kubernetes YAML? missing Resource metadata

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am following [Building a GITOPS pipeline with EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/building-a-gitops-pipeline-with-amazon-eks/).

After `flux create source` and `flux create kustomization`

my fleet-intra repo

```
tree -L 3
.
└── adorable-mushroom-1655535375
    ├── flux-system
    │   ├── gotk-components.yaml
    │   ├── gotk-sync.yaml
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── guestbook-gitops.yaml
```

I have problem with kustomization

```
flux get kustomizations

NAME        REVISION                                        SUSPENDED   READY   MESSAGE                                                                                                                                          
flux-system main/75d8189db82f1c2c77d22a9deb6baea06f179d0c   False       False   failed to decode Kubernetes YAML from /tmp/kustomization-985813897/adorable-mushroom-1655535375/guestbook-gitops.yaml: missing Resource metadata
```

My guestbook-gitops.yaml  looks like this

```
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: guestbook-gitops
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 1h0m0s
  path: ./deploy
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: guestbook-gitops
```

What is wrong with metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [link](https://github.com/weaveworks/guestbook-gitops/blob/master/deploy/kustomization.yaml) you had shared there sample kustomization yaml.  you can prepare kustomize yaml in similar manner and check it.

Answer (score 0):

I was following a similar guide where I ran a similar command to create this kustomization which was then exported into a file. And like in the linked guide, there was a `--validation=client` flag.
The `flux create kustomization` command produced this warning, which was also exported into the result file:

```
Flag --validation has been deprecated, this arg is no longer used, all resources are validated using server-side apply dry-run
```

So I removed this line from my yaml file and it worked immediately.